# how to add external jar directory to classpath?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project , which is maven driven ( obviously ) .

Now i want to have a directory in desktop( for storing all 3rd party jars) and want to somehow connect this to my project .

Any idea , how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Start using a repository manager and upload those jars their and it's done....

Comment: All your dependencies need to be referenced in the pom.xml. if not maven will not be able to build and not able to generate a standalone jar.

Comment: i have dependencies in pom.xml. Also i want to maintain a extra directory , as in that directory i will put those jars which are need for that time only

Answer (score 0):

From eclipse -> right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external jars

Alternately , 
add classpath in your local machine's .bashrc file

example to copy paste and edit path :

CLASSPATH="/home/user/eclipse-workspace/seleniumGrid/lib/json.jar:/home/user/eclipse-workspace/seleniumGrid/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar

export CLASSPATH

.bashrc is loaded when you start your terminal once atleast.
so start your terminal and then classpath will be set

you can try to see what your classpath is by typing below line in your terminal shell :

echo $classpath